# Can I loadlibrary with multiple dlls that has same function names?

Tags: c++, windows, loadlibrary

If I have a.dll and b.dll, both of them have exactly same function names. for example, foo(), bar() from a.dll and foo(), bar() from b.dll. Will the later loaded one override/replace the former loaded one?

Comment: With `LoadLibrary` you use `GetProcAddress`, specifying the DLL handle, to get pointers to the functions, so it's not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both dll's can be loaded with loadlibrary (even if one is a copy of the other in a different directory).
Nothing will override anything ,since in order to call a function from either one you need to use the GetProcAddress routine.